# Communication between Oracle Virtualhost Ubuntu's

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, ssh, oracle

I have 2 Ubuntus in my Oracle Virtualbox installed in Windows 7.Now I wanted to SSH communicate between them so I tried to find the IP of the both the Ubuntus, when I tried ifconfig both Server are giving same result there is no difference in the IP details as below,

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:a2:f0:56:ff  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:20:05:cf  
          inet6 addr: fe80::c417:41f6:4550:9a02/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7199 (7.1 KB)  TX bytes:18336 (18.3 KB)

enp0s8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f3:5c:fa  
          inet addr:10.0.3.15  Bcast:10.0.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::acd0:f921:620d:3704/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:66 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:141 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8806 (8.8 KB)  TX bytes:13863 (13.8 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:114 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:9379 (9.3 KB)  TX bytes:9379 (9.3 KB
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

by default VirtualBox Networking [Settings|Network] uses a "NAT Adapter". This virtual adapter goes directly from the VM to the PC's network card without being visible to the local machine or other VMs.

What you want to do is either A) used a "Bridged Adapter" which will set the VM to look like a NEW DEVICE on your local network and request a new DHCP IP address for it just like another computer. Option B) is to use the "Host-Only Adapter" which creates a virtual network between your VMs and the Host that is localized only to the Host computer.

You should look up these topics in the manual. This is just a brief glimpse of the features.

Comment: thanks for your response +1, If it is set then internet connection is not working from these Ubuntu's in VH.Is this something am missing here?